# Is there any alias for text fields when using Active Admin in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Am using Active Admin, In my database, the field name is big. So, I want to make an alias for the field in the display. I want something like this

```
f.input :incorrect_price_and_designer_1 , :alias=>"incorrect 1"
```

Please, let me know if anything is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support in advance..

inc_answer.input :incorrect_price_1, :label => "Incorrect 1"

This works fine...

It might be helpful for some people